# Sinusoidal ground

Tags: tikz-pgf

What I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{wheel} = [draw, circle]
  \tikzstyle{mass} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 2cm]
  \tikzstyle{spring} = [decorate, decoration = {zigzag, pre length = 0.3cm, post length = 0.3cm, segment length = 6}]
  \tikzstyle{damper} = [decoration = {markings, mark connection node = dmp, mark = at position 0.5 with 
    {
     \node (dmp) [inner sep = 0pt, transform shape, rotate = -90, minimum width = 5pt, minimum height = 5pt, draw=none] {};
     \draw ($(dmp.north east)+(1.5pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(1.5pt,0)$);
     \draw ($(dmp.north)+(0,-1.5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,1.5pt)$);
    }
   }, decorate]
  \tikzstyle{groundflat} = [fill, pattern = north east lines, draw = none, minimum width = 0.75cm, minimum height = 0.3cm]
% \tikzstyle{groundsine1} = [fill, pattern = north east lines, draw = none, minimum width = 0.75cm, minimum height = 0.3cm]
  \node[wheel] (u) {$u$};
  \node[mass, above of = u, node distance = 3cm] (m) {$y$};
  \node (gf) [groundflat, anchor = north, minimum width = 5cm] at (u.south) {};
  \draw (gf.north east) -- (gf.north west);
  \draw [-] (u.north) |- ++(0.5,0.25cm)coordinate (uright);
  \draw [-] (u.north) |- ++(-0.5,0.25cm)coordinate (uleft);
  \draw [spring] (uleft) -- ($(m.south) +(-0.5,0)$);
  \draw [damper] (uright) -- ($(m.south) +(0.5,0)$);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I now want the ground to be a sine wave and the wheel sitting on the first peak.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Just found this one: [Tikz Cordinate Positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223588/tikz-cordinate-positioning)

But I'm not really able to put it together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of drawing the mechanical scheme before the ground, it's easier to draw the sinusoidal ground and place the machine on top of it.

On page 128 in `pgfmanual` you can see how to draw a sinusoidal line:

```
  \draw (0,0) sin (1,.5) coordinate (top) cos (2,0) sin (3,-.5) cos (4,0) sin (5,.5) cos (6,0);
```

The first peak is at coordinate (1,.5) (named `top`) and we can place the `wheel` on top of it with

```
  \node[wheel, above=0pt of top] (u) {$u$};
```

And as the rest of scheme is already drawn based on `u`, you won't need to many changes. I've changed old syntax `above of=` for newer `above= of` (needs `positioning` library, page 229).

By the way, please, consider to change from `\tikzstyle` to `\tikzset` syntax: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, positioning}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{wheel} = [draw, circle]
  \tikzstyle{mass} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 2cm]
  \tikzstyle{spring} = [decorate, decoration = {zigzag, pre length = 0.3cm, post length = 0.3cm, segment length = 6}]
  \tikzstyle{damper} = [decoration = {markings, mark connection node = dmp, mark = at position 0.5 with 
    {
     \node (dmp) [inner sep = 0pt, transform shape, rotate = -90, minimum width = 5pt, minimum height = 5pt, draw=none] {};
     \draw ($(dmp.north east)+(1.5pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(1.5pt,0)$);
     \draw ($(dmp.north)+(0,-1.5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,1.5pt)$);
    }
   }, decorate]
  \tikzstyle{groundflat} = [fill, pattern = north east lines, draw = none, minimum width = 0.75cm, minimum height = 0.3cm]

  \draw[fill, pattern=north east lines] (0,0) sin (1,.5) coordinate (top) cos (2,0) sin (3,-.5) cos (4,0) sin (5,.5) cos (6,0) |- (0,-1)--cycle;

  \node[wheel, above=0pt of top] (u) {$u$};
  \node[mass, above =2cm of u] (m) {$y$};
  \draw [-] (u.north) |- ++(0.5,0.25cm)coordinate (uright);
  \draw [-] (u.north) |- ++(-0.5,0.25cm)coordinate (uleft);
  \draw [spring] (uleft) -- ($(m.south) +(-0.5,0)$);
  \draw [damper] (uright) -- ($(m.south) +(0.5,0)$);

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. Although it is a little tedious to change the frequency.

Comment: @Pascal You can also use a `plot`